# How to prevent data loss when an error occurs while writing to a file?

Tags: c

I am writing bytes to a file with `fwrite()`.

I am considering the situation where `fwrite()` might fail.

I am unsure, but I assume the file will be corrupted if the function fails mid-write.
I considered making my own buffer, but I think the underlying `write()` function chops up the data however it wants, so there might be multiple writes. In the same way I think `fwrite()` is buffered, so there may be less writes than write functions.

Currently, my only idea is to make the classic 2-file method where one file has old data, and one has new data. For this, I am unsure which approach would be best (alternating files / copy file to _file_old, and then overwrite _file...)

Unsure about my options with renaming files and being able to detect them.

I am aiming for a pure C99 with only the standard library.

Comment: File writes generally do not fail unless you run out of disk space completely in which case any 2-file method will also fail. If you're really concerned about this get a RAID system, or similar.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError The two-file method fails safely -- the old file is still intact.

Comment: Even if `fwrite` reports success, you cannot be sure that the data will be written to permanent storage (such as a hard disk). For example, operating systems usually use a write cache, so the data can still get lost, for example if there is a power failure or if the operating system crashes. Are you looking for a way to ensure that the data is fully written to permanent storage, even in the event of a power failure/OS crash?

Comment: @chqrlie : Sorry about that, sloppy mistake. It does return the number of elements returned. Too late to edit the comment therefore I will remove it as it is misinformation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resorting to a 2 file approach is the only way to ensure complete file consistency especially in case the program is interrupted by the user or for some other reason.

Even with a 2 file approach, you should check for proper completion of all output operations:

- compare the return value of all `fwrite(ptr, size, nmemb, fp)` calls to `nmemb`, the number of elements requested.
- check the return value of `fflush()`: non zero means failure.
- check the return value of the `fclose()` call: again non zero means failure, probably caused by an error when flushing the stream buffer or updating the inode data.

If all goes well, the new file should have been written completely and it should be safe to rename the output file with `rename()`, thereby removing the original file.  POSIX systems guarantee that the rename operation is atomic and remove the old file automatically, but other operating systems might require you to remove the original file first, which is a classic design flaw, or even refuse to rename the file if it is still open by some process.  Again you should check the return value of `rename` and report this failure with an appropriate error message constructed with `strerror(errno)`.