# How to make sure a file isn't corrupted?

Tags: c

When I `fwrite()` to a file, the write might fail. If a subsequent `rename()` also fails, I have no way to check the file's integrity until I load it and it doesn't pass value validity checks.

I had an idea to write a special value in the first byte, and then at the very end, use `fseek(SEEK_SET)`, and change the byte to one that doesn't signify corruption.

Would this be a good idea, and are there any better approaches that you know of?

Comment: If a call to `fwrite` fails then retry.  Same with a failed call to `rename`.

Comment: *When I fwrite() to a file, the write might fail.* You should check the value retrned by `fwrite` *and* by `rename`.

Comment: If the call fails then it will return with a value indicating a problem.

Comment: *I have no way to check the file's integrity until I load it and it doesn't pass value validity checks.* If there is a concern, do that **before** you rename. Read the whole file and check it contains what you intended to write. Of course you might get a false positive there too, but 'confidence' is what you aim for.

Comment: @dbush "retry" how many times?

Comment: Create the file under a temporary name. When you finish, rename to the real name.

Comment: What do you mean “if a subsequent `rename()` also fails”? Are you renaming the file to a name that indicates an error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could intentionally corrupt the data file during operation, but that would be detrimental to other processes that may use the file.

A 2 file approach is a safe solution for reasonably small text files as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77092675/4593267).